# Serial Communication in Raspberry pi 3 B+

Tags: serial, gsm, python-2.x

I want to communicate between Raspberry pi 3 B+ and GSM GPRS A6. I tried and I am unable to send data to GPRS Module from Raspberry pi.

Now, I know that GPIO serial port is disabled by default in newer Operating Systems (in my case Raspbian Stretch), so I have enabled it by adding following line in config.txt file,

```
enable_uart=1
```

Here's my Code:

```
import serial
import time

port = "/dev/ttyS0"
COMM = serial.Serial(port, baudrate=115200)

while(1):
    COMM.write("AT\r")
    print (COMM.read(5))
```

This command is supposed to return "OK", but it does not and nothing is printed. I am using python 2.7.

Some people suggested me to send data using this method,

```
COMM.write('AT' + '\r')
```

I tried but it didn't help.

There is no problem with my GPRS module. It works file with arduino. So, what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `\n` instead of `\r` and let us know whether it changes anything. If it does I'll explain why.

Comment: @MarkSmith So I tried \n, and now sometimes it shows correct output and  some time it shows garbage.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that it's better than it was? Now at least working somewhat, some of the time?

Comment: yes... So, whats the reason behind '\n'?

Answer (score 2):

When you write `"\n"` in a C program, the compiler replaces it with a single character.  The `\` is called an 'escape', and it gives a special meaning to the character following it -- in this case the `n`.

Commands sent to the devices must be terminated with a suitable line ending, so it knows where the command ends.  Common line endings are `\n` (which is a single number 10, or hex 0x0A) used by Unix-like systems, and `\r\n` (which is a 13 and a 10, or 0x0D 0x0A), used by Windows.  I imagine your modules might work either combination.  Nothing, as far as I know, uses just a `\r`.

There are various ways you can send it.

```
COMM.write("AT\n")
```

is fine.

However

```
COMM.write('AT' + '\r')
```

will not do what you want.  The reasoning is a bit involved, but for now, probably don't worry about it and just use the former.

Comment: In fact plain `\r` is the [line terminator for AT (aka Hayes) commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set#Syntactical_definitions).  However, using `\r\n` is okay, and if you set the modem into verbose mode it will reply with `\r\n` as well.  So your suggestion to just use `"AT\n"` will not work in this case.

Comment: Gosh, so it is. Strange thing then is that I don't know why changing to \n helped.